# Color of custom font in navgation controller (setTextColor): gray instead of white

Tags: objective-c, fonts, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I am trying to set custom font and color (white) for font in my app's navigation bar title. **Instead of white I get gray text color.**

Here is the code I'm using to set custom font:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
label.minimumFontSize = 10.0;
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueLTCom-MdCn" size:24.0]];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[label setText:@"View title"];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:label];
```

Same thing happened when I tried to set custom font color in UITableView sections.

I know about some problems with Helvetica Neue in iPhone apps development but the color of this font works well in other parts of my projects.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I've (deliberately) overriden default font for the whole application [as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7607281/963881).

The solution was to remove this override (all the `#import`'s and the remove `.m` file from the target, or just delete both of the class files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other `.ttf` fonts just to test if they work? I wonder if there is something wrong with the font file itself. [try this directory](http://www.nadimnabi.com/fonts/) and see if it works.

Comment: Yes, I've tried using: `[label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0]]` and the colors stays gray.