# how set custom font for whole all labels in a view?

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, uilabel

I would like to set custom font for my complete view

I have referred the following 
[How do I set a custom font for the whole application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607108/how-do-i-set-a-custom-font-for-the-whole-application)

But this suggests only font type and font size for the labels
currently am using following code snippet for all labels which is increasing the redundancy.

```
label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Is it possible to add text color and background color in similar fashion ?

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of something else, but it's not a duplicate of the question it's marked as.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
-(void)changeFont:(UIView *) view{
    for (id View in [view subviews]) {
        if ([View isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) { 
                [View setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Candara" size:26]];
                View.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                [View setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        }
        if ([View isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
            [self changeFont:View];
        }
    }
}
```

call this methode and pass your `view`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using iOS 5+ and have the labels inside a custom view (or can put them into a custom view) then you can use `UIAppearance` and `UIAppearanceContainer`. They are made for exactly this scenario.

The relevant method is `+appearanceWhenContainedIn:`, which allows you to set the appearance (font, color, background image etc.) when the view class you are targeting is contained inside a view of a given class.

```
// Set appearance of UILabels within MyViews
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyView class], nil] 
    setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyView class], nil] 
    setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceCodePro-Black" size:24]];
```

I put this into the app delegate, but you could put it somewhere else. This will change the appearance of all `UILabel` instances which are inside a view of class `MyView`.

Check out the WWDC 2011 video for Session 114 for details.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a `category` for `label` like"

```
    @interface UILabel(SMLabelCatogary)
    - (void) setCustomLabelDesign;
    @end

    @implementation UILabel(SMLabelCatogary)
    - (void) setCustomLabelDesign{
        label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
    @end
```

Now call `setCustomLabelDesign` with your label (as `[label setCustomLabelDesign]`) to customize that in this accordance.